# How to store floas with given precision using Python SQLAlchemy and SQLite DB

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have code which uses SQLAlchemy (Python) with a SQLite DB.
It used to have float fields defined like:

```
perf = Column(Float)
```

but now I need to limit the precision, e.g. to 3.

I tried to set the precision in the c'tor but that had *no effect* on the SQLite schema that was created and more importantly on the stored values. I expected to see something like FLOAT(3) in the DB schema, just like I see VARCHAR(128) when setting a string length.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float
perf = Column(Float(precision=3))
```

I could write a `@property` for each float field to do the casting, maybe even write my own float type, but there *must* be a better and simpler way to achieve the same...

**UPDATE**

I wrote a `TypeDecorator` like so:

```
class PrecisionFloat(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Float
    cache_ok = True
    
    def __init__(self, precision=3, *args, **kwargs):  # @UnusedVariable
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.precision = precision
    
    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):  # @UnusedVariable
        return round(value, self.precision)
```

This works, but seems like unnecessary as precision is supposedly supported.

Comment: The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) makes no mention of an optional precision value for FLOATs. What leads you to believe that such a thing exists for SQLite?

Comment: Because `SQLAlchemy ` docs don't say `precision` parameter is valid only for some backends. Also, *reducing* precision is something that you can always do. Anyway, it didn't work...